# Distinguish flutter code is run by native code or not?

Tags: flutter

I have a iOS native project embed flutter codes with FlutterViewController , Now I want to run this flutter directly in AndroidStudio . So I have to distinguish whether the flutter program is run by Native Project or Pure Flutter Project 's main.dart .

Is there anyway to do this?( --dart-define will pollute the whole SDK and all the flutter projects . I think it's not a good way to do this)

Comment: I don't think there's any way. Can you flag wherever you call "invokeMethod" - which is used to call native code?